Removing Shelf for Electrical Panel Clearance
I’m getting solar panels installed, and the electrician who was here today mentioned that the inspector will need a 3 ft clearance in front of the electrical panel. The problem is, there’s a shelf mounted to the wall directly beneath the panel, and I’m not sure how to go about removing it.
The shelf is a permanent fixture, and I’ve attached some photos to this post to show the setup. Has anyone dealt with a similar situation before? Do you think the inspector will be strict about the 3 ft clearance even though the shelf is a bit lower? If it does need to be removed, what’s the best way to do it without damaging the wall too much?
The shelf is quite secure and does not budge at all. I don't see any fasteners when looking inside; it appears to be adhered & caulked to the wall.





what does the question have to do with solar panels?

the question is about removing the shelf ... the references to the electrical panel are just irrelevant clutter

it has to go, start by removing the molding around the bottom. The next question is do you want to save it or not

@jsotola Solar Panels => Electrical work requiring permit/inspection => Inspector will see and likely have an issue with working space. Totally logical. Though when I had my heavy-up, I moved things and marked 30" x 36" on the floor with painter's tape - which my electrician thought was a bit much and better to not indicate just how close things really were. In the end the inspector didn't have an issue. But I had nothing permanently installed in the required space. With permanent shelving - which the baseboard confirms - this is a real problem.


The shelf does not budge at all, and I don't see any fasteners when looking inside; it appears to be adhered & caulked to the wall



Yes, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact is exactly right as the relation of my story to solar panels. In fact, the panels have already been installed, but the final connect to the electrical grid requires a passed inspection, of which apparently one of the items is 3 ft clearance in front of the electrical panel



The electrician himself says that while it's an item the inspector will check for, the insepector may or may not let it go and I could take the risk. Yes, my question here was directed towards the off-chance code inspectors who may be lurking around on StackExchange ;P


I'm guessing my best bet is, after removing the molding, take a blade and start scoring around the edges?

Well it's absolutely a code violation.  Code requires that a clear working space in front of electrical panels be kept clear AT ALL TIMES that is the width of the equipment (but at least 30"), 36" standback room, and 78" high and on a flat floor not a stairway etc.


Score the joints/edges around the trim and the cabinet/shelf with a utility knife
Remove trim
If any fasteners can be found, remove them. Try running a magnet along the inside of the cabinet; with luck, you'll find a screw or two that was filled and painted that can be cleaned out and removed (or a plug bit for a drill if you can't get it cleaned out). If there is a gap at the wall, something thin like a hacksaw blade might be useful for finding any screws into the walls.
Try being gentle at first by simply pulling hard. If that fails, try a pry bar at the back where the stud is located and pry out.
If you can't find fasteners and it doesn't pull from the wall, we're gonna break it. Hit the non-wall side of the cabinet from the inside until that board pulls free. Then middle shelf, top, and bottom.
The side and back adjacent to the wall can be a real problem. You will most likely have some minor wall repair. Again, try a pry bar where the studs are located and on the floor.


Note that the repair doesn't need to be done before the electrical inspection. The removal does. Of course you can put a similar but freestanding shelf back into that corner.

If you're really careful about removing the trim you may be able to reuse it on the wall.

Thank you for the detailed response! This shelf was present from the previous homeowner, and I do prefer to reuse if possible.

@keshlam putting anything there is a code violation, as the shelf (apparently) was in the first place, (possibly not, depending which panels are new but it does not look like there's 30 inches to the wall, so probably) as it infringes on the required working space that is to be kept clear, always. That space is specifically NOT to be used for storage.

@Ecnerwal: Ah. My electrician and inspector had no problem with a desk being in roughly equivalent position. I don't know what rationale they applied.

@keshlam  perhaps because it was (presumably) not permanently mounted.

Technophile: That's what I suggested, replacing it with or rebuilding it as freestanding furniture. @Ecnerwal seemed to be saying that was unacceptable. If so, my situation should have been in violation. One or more of us are confused, probably me, but I'm not 110% certain

From article 110.26(B) "Clear Spaces. Working space required by this section shall not be used for storage. When normally enclosed live parts are exposed for inspection or servicing, the working space, if in a passageway or general open space, shall be suitably guarded." If it didn't completely infringe on the panels it might have been roughly eqivalent while still passing the letter, or perhaps they were assuming (likely corectly) that most homeowners would clear the space only until they left the building, so they were not fighting it.
